# Truncate text in TTStyledTextLabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, three20, ttstyledtextlabel

I am using a `TTStyledTextLabel` in my project to parse the hyperlinks, it all works fine. The only problem I am facing is to truncate a long text - show ellipses if the text does not fit in the bounds of `TTStyledTextLabel`.

In other terms, I need the same behavior as a UILabel which adds ellipses to indicate that some text is clipped. I have searched in `TTStyledTextLabel` and `TTStyledText` classes, there is no provision to achieve this. The following is the code which I have used in my `UITableViewCell` subclass to set the frame of `TTStyledTextLabel` appropriately:

```
-(void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
.
.
.
    CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(self.contentView.frame.size.width -TEXT_OFFSET_WIDTH, TT_TEXT_MAX_HEIGHT);
    [[[self textLabelTTStyled] text] setWidth:maxSize.width];
    [[self textLabelTTStyled] sizeToFit];
    double heigthForTTLabel = [[[self textLabelTTStyled] text] height];
    if (heigthForTTLabel > maxSize.height)
        heigthForTTLabel = maxSize.height;  // Do not exceed the maximum height for the TTStyledTextLabel.
**// The Text was supposed to clip here when maximum height is set!**
    CGSize mTempSize = CGSizeMake([[[self textLabelTTStyled] text] width], heigthForTTLabel);
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(TEXT_OFFSET_X,TEXT_OFFSET_Y,mTempSize.width, mTempSize.height);
    self.textLabelTTStyled.frame = frame;
.
.
.
}
```

And in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I am setting text like this to my `TTStyledTextLabel`:

```
TTStyledText *styledStatusMessage = [TTStyledText textFromXHTML:@"This is a really long text, how long can this go on? This is a really long text, how long can this go on? This is a really long text, how long can this go on? This is a really long text, how long can this go on? This is a really long text, how long can this go on? This is a really long text, how long can this go on?"
    lineBreaks:YES URLs:YES];

if (nil == styledStatusMessage) {
  styledStatusMessage = [TTStyledText textWithURLs:[statusMessage title] lineBreaks:YES];
  [[cell textLabelTTStyled] setText:styledStatusMessage];
}
```

The excessive text is simply being discarded, the ellipses are not added by default to indicate that text is clipped. Any solutions to this problem?

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are using a private api Three20 which is having a chance oof rejection from appstore.Just check once before you upload.
Genrally you can set any set any custom button with setting title on it

[button setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];
[button setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0)];  - This line can be used for settting title edges. Hope it helps.